# JavaScript iterate through an object arrays(unknown number of content array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to iterate through an object which has unknown number of arrays and also i dont know number of data in  each array because im pulling it from a database like this for example.
[image]

i can know how many arrays in object with data.length so first for loops condition will be data.length but because i dont know how many data in each array how can i decide second for loop condition ? thanks

```
for(var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    for(var k = 0; k <= ????; k++) {
        data[i][k].locationlat
    }
}
```

Comment: `data[i].length`

Comment: yea thanks im new :D

Answer (score 1):

So you want to iterate through a 2-dimensional array? Would something like this work?

```
var num_d1 = data.length;
for (var i=0; i<num_d1; i++) {
    var num_d2 = data[i].length;
    for (var k=0; k<num_d2; k++) {
        console.log('Latitude: ', data[i][k].locationlat)
    }
}
```